# Pandas replacing the entries and NaNs with the average of first two entries

Tags: python, pandas

This is a very strange dataset that I do not know how to preprocess as following example:

```
Year, ID, feature1, feature2, target1
2008, 1,  10,       20,       5
2008, 1,  12,       25,       6
2008, 1,  NaN,      NaN,      4
2008, 1,  NaN,      NaN,      7
2008, 1,  NaN,      NaN,      3
2008, 1,  NaN,      NaN,      5
2008, 2,  22,       16,       7
2008, 2,  24,       14,       3
2008, 2,  NaN,      NaN,      5
2008, 2,  NaN,      NaN,      6
2008, 2,  NaN,      NaN,      9
2008, 3,  12,       15,       6
2008, 3,  NaN,      NaN,      1
....
```

The question is that I would like to replace the first two entries with value by their average, AND also fill the NaN with average from the first two values for columns `feature1` and `feature2`. If there is only one column that has an entry like `ID == 3`, I will just ffill.

Example output:

```
Year, ID, feature1, feature2, target1
2008, 1,  11,       22.5,     5
2008, 1,  11,       22.5,     6
2008, 1,  11,       22.5,     4
2008, 1,  11,       22.5,     7
2008, 1,  11,       22.5,     3
2008, 1,  11,       22.5,     5
2008, 2,  23,       15,       7
2008, 2,  23,       15,       3
2008, 2,  23,       15,       5
2008, 2,  23,       15,       6
2008, 2,  23,       15,       9
2008, 3,  12,       15,       6
2008, 3,  12,       15,       1
....
```

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `transform` `mean`

```
g = df.groupby(['Year','ID'])
df['feature1'] = g['feature1'].transform('mean')
df['feature2'] = g['feature2'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ill give it a try!

Comment: It works for me, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby_transform` to update the values of `feature1` and `feature2` columns:

```
df.update(df.groupby(['Year', 'ID'])['feature1', 'feature2'].transform('mean'))
print(df)

# Output:
    Year  ID  feature1  feature2  target1
0   2008   1      11.0      22.5        5
1   2008   1      11.0      22.5        6
2   2008   1      11.0      22.5        4
3   2008   1      11.0      22.5        7
4   2008   1      11.0      22.5        3
5   2008   1      11.0      22.5        5
6   2008   2      23.0      15.0        7
7   2008   2      23.0      15.0        3
8   2008   2      23.0      15.0        5
9   2008   2      23.0      15.0        6
10  2008   2      23.0      15.0        9
11  2008   3      12.0      15.0        6
12  2008   3      12.0      15.0        1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ill give it a try!

Comment: I got it working too but I marked the first answer. Thank you too for your help!